# ListVew ScrollToBottom with last element aligned with bottom edge

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview

What I'm looking for is basically the regular console behavior. It starts adding text at the top, when the window is filled it starts scrolling automatically to keep the most recently added line in view.

The problem I'm having is that the `ScrollToBottom` on `ListView` takes the *n* last items (where n is how many will fit) but then aligns those items to the top of the control, leaving a gap at the bottom.

It could be partially solved with adding:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Which correctly keeps the last item aligned with bottom. Until I call ScrollToBottom (then the gap reappears).

Below is the smallest code snippet I could come up with that still shows this behavior.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollToBottomTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
    <ListView x:Name="listView">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Background="Gray"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ScrollToBottomTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        listView.Items.Add("abc");
                        ScrollToBottom();
                    });
                    Thread.Sleep(250);
                }
            })
            { IsBackground = true }.Start();
        }

        private void ScrollToBottom()
        {
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(listView) > 0)
            {
                Border border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(listView, 0);
                ScrollViewer scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
                scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would be very grateful for any hints.

Comment: Create the ListViewItem, then add it, the call BringIntoView on the item

Comment: Mind making that an answer instead? It was a good try but it gave me another problem. Instead of a gap at bottom it put a partial row there, it's still the top item that's aligned with the top edge.

Answer (score 0):

Create the ListViewItem, then add it, and then call BringIntoView on the item.